# Order the profile wall (publications, and activity feeds) in a Facebook way

Tags: php, facebook, social-networking, profile

I'm doing kinda social site. I have noticed that on my facebook profile wall publications, and activity feed(likes, becoming friends etc.) are separated - publications are in 1 place and activity feed at another. That's not a problem but here comes the thing I can't figure out. The activity feed and publications are not only separated by type but also by date.
Here's what I mean.

> ```
>  **Today** 
> publication -> Windom is very tired. 
> publication -> DAMN! I'm so angry!!! 
> act.feed -> Windom became friends with John and Steve. 
> act. feed -> Windom likes AC/DC, Guitars and Rock.
>
> **Yesterday** 
> publication -> Bla bla bla 
> act.feed -> Windom likes PHP, Table tennis and Vermeer. 
> act. feed-> Windom and Lisa are now friends.
> ```

etc.

There could also be days in which there is only activity feed or only publications. How to do that in my site with php & mysql? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the easiest way is to get the data seperately then place them into seperate arrays for topics (such as message, type, created dtae, etc) making sure that you always have the message aray go publications then act.feed and the date created is publications then act. feed... essentially so it's broekn up into two areas sorted by time (pub1,pub2,feed1,feed2). Once you have the arrays done... do a large array sort using the ascending as time. That way you can sort everything into one array.
So now that I have the brief idea of the structure out of my head, here's how we'd do it.

Start off with json1 and json2 (you publications and your feed). Do two do while statments which are both the same in the data they sort but different for which json they use...
example:

> $fi=0;
>
> do {
>
> $tmp_message_feed[$fi] = $json1['message'];
>
> $tmp_message_feed[$fi] = json1['created_time'];
>
> $fi++;
>
> } while ($total_feed_messages>$fi)

Something like that. Then create another one for json 2 with the exact same categories.

Next merge the arrays of each category. [Using this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Then we end it with an array multisort:

```
array_multisort($tmp_created_time, SORT_DESC, SORT_STRING, $tmp_message);
```

And then it's all sorted in those arrays so you can do a for each or the same count method as above to spit the information out however you wish!

I hope this helped!

Jon